# OCaml Stack of tuples

Tags: stack, ocaml, tuples

I am trying to create a stack of tuples in OCaml using the following piece of code

```
let (k : (string*string) Stack.t) = Stack.create ;;
```

But when doing so i get an error while compiling telling

```
Error: This expression has type unit -> 'a Stack.t
   but an expression was expected of type (string * string) Stack.t
```

Am pretty new to OCaml. Can someone point out where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Stack.create` is a function which takes the value `()` (of type `unit`) and give you back a stack.

So you should do:

```
let (k : (string*string) Stack.t) = Stack.create ();;
```

if you write `Stack.create`, you just speak about the function, not the result.